# Extract value attribute from a HTML snippet

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to extract `value` property from a HTML file. I used `querySelectorAll` to get all the nodes in the file. Could anyone please help how do I *only* fetch `value` property from the file.

```js
const nodes = document.querySelectorAll("add")
console.log(nodes)
```

```html
<div>
  <add value="abc"></add>
  <add value="def"></add>
  <add value="ghi"></add>
</div>
```

Comment: From the file or from the element? Your context is not clear. There are multiple value attributes. Are you looping? Show your code.

Comment: You do realize that `<add>` is not valid HTML?

Comment: The `add` part was some part of xml file. For data extracting purpose, I have added it to a HTML file. @EmielZuurbier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure to check that the selected nodes have the attribute `value` by adding `[value]` to the query.

Note: here i use the ES6 spread operator to get the NodeList as an array.

```js
const nodes = document.querySelectorAll("add[value]")
console.log([...nodes].map(n => n.getAttribute("value")))
```

```html
<div>
  <add value="abc"></add>
  <add value="def"></add>
  <add value="ghi"></add>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.prototype.map` with `Array.from`:

```js
const nodes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("add")).map(el => el.getAttribute('value'))
console.log(nodes)
```

```html
<div>
  <add value="abc"></add>
  <add value="def"></add>
  <add value="ghi"></add>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can map over the node collection, and call `getAttribute()` on each:

```js
const nodes = document.querySelectorAll('add');

const values = Array.from(nodes).map(node => node.getAttribute('value'));

console.log(values);
```

```html
<div>
  <add value="abc"></add>
  <add value="def"></add>
  <add value="ghi"></add>
</div>
```